# How to use an IF statement with arraylist object and calling the size() method on it. In Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to solve the code query:

> Create a program that uses a multidimensional array to store student grades. The first dimension should be a number for each student, and the second dimension should be for each student’s grades. Display the average of all the grades earned by each student and an overall average for every student.

Below is my code:

I created 3 grades for 2 students.

```
int [] [] students_grades = new int[2][3];

students_grades[0][0] = 13;
students_grades[0][1] = 23;
students_grades[0][2] = 34;

students_grades[1][0] = 31;
students_grades[1][1] = 32;
students_grades[1][2] = 43;

int rows = 2;
int columns = 3;
int i, j;

for (i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
    for ( j = 0; j < rows; j++) {

        List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        myList.add(students_grades[j][i]);
        if (myList.size()==3) {
           System.out.println("************************************************");
           System.out.println("This is the grades for Students 1: ");                 System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------");
           for (int element : myList) {
              System.out.println(element);
           }

        }
    }
    System.out.println(" ");
}
```

But I am not getting an output from the for loop statement in the if brackets.

Comment: Why are you using a List at all and have you really understood the assignment because I see no attempt to calculate an average value?

Comment: You might want to update the title, looks like people are misunderstanding your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to print only the grades of first student,try this:

```
int [] [] students_grades = new int[2][3];
        students_grades[0][0] = 13;
        students_grades[0][1] = 23;
        students_grades[0][2] = 34;

        students_grades[1][0] = 31;
        students_grades[1][1] = 32;
        students_grades[1][2] = 43;

        int rows = 2;
        int columns = 3;
        int i, j;
        List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for ( j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                myList.add(students_grades[i][j]);
                if (myList.size() == 3) {
                    System.out.println("************************************************");
                    System.out.println("This is the grades for Students 1: ");                 System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------");
                    for (int element : myList) {
                        System.out.println(element);
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println(" ");
        }

    }
```

Comment: But why use a List object, why not print the elements of the array directly?

Comment: You can also print them out directly. Since, the question was how to use an IF statement with Arraylist object and calling the size() method, I implemented with the Arraylist

Comment: Well the title of the question to be exact but why just copy bad code from question? Anyway, I doubt this answer will help OP with the homework.

Answer (score -1):

myList is being defined within the inner loop, this means every iteration in the loop is creating a new list, so the list length will never be 3.

To fix this, you need to assign a new ArrayList to myList within the outer loop, like so:

```
   for (j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
        List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for ( i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
            myList.add(students_grades[j][i]);
            if (myList.size()==3) {
                System.out.println("************************************************");
                System.out.println("This is the grades for Students 1: ");                 System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------");
             for (int element : myList) {
                  System.out.println(element);
             }

        }
    }
```

EDIT:
Since rows is set to 2, the if condition would never be satisfied. Swapping the for statements would satisfy the if condition.